# Hive select with WHERE tuple IN array condition

Tags: sql, hive

very simple.

```
SELECT something FROM table WHERE (a,b) IN ((a_1,b_1),...,(a_n,b_n))
```

This works in MySQL but doesn't work in Hive. Is there a workaround? I tried something like

```
WHERE array_contains(array(array(a_1,b_1),...,array(a_n,b_n)), array(a,b))
```

but array_contains only seems to work with primitive types.

*Edit*: for the record, (a,b) is (year,month,day) in my specific case so I could theoretically exploit date functions, but still, I think it's a bit weird that this isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

OK so far the only workaround I found is

```
WHERE ((a=a_1 AND b=b_1) OR ... OR (a=a_n AND b=b_n))
```

which is fine since it's going to be auto-generated, but still it would be nice to have the above functionality...

Comment: another workaround: `concat(a,b) in (concat(a1,b1), concat(a2,b2) .. concat(an, bn))`. perhaps use `concat_ws()` to add spacing character(s). Not sure how nulls would be handled.